# Fullcalendar popup not fully visible when we have more events in the single cell

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have been working with the [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/) library.

Struggling the issue with Calendar popup when I have more events in the single cell it's going inside the footer.
as shown in the below image.
[image]

I have tried to fix with `z-index` but didn't work.

As I searched for fix found this [pull request](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/3201/files) which doesn't merge to master.

I couldn't find a way that when we can move the popup.

Could you please help me to fix this.

Comment: How would z-index fix anything here, you do not have a problem on the z-axis ...

Comment: if you have too many events showing up in one cell, you can use the eventLimit option to reduce them https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/ . The rest will then be shown in a popup when the "more" button is clicked.

Comment: I used event limit, Above pop up came after clicking on more button only.

Answer (score 1):

This issue I was fixed by taking the closest row from the calendar and comparing with the last row.
if both are same then only changing the popup position.
Please let me know if anyone has any other good solution

```
  // If it is last row of in the calendar.
        $elem.on('click', '.fc-more', function (evt) {
          var closestRow = angular.element(this).parents().closest('.fc-row.fc-week')[0];
          var lastRow = angular.element(this).parents().find('.fc-row.fc-week:last')[0];
          if (closestRow === lastRow && screen.width <= 1700) {
            var popElement = angular.element('.fc-popover.fc-more-popover');
            popElement.css({ 'top': popElement.position().top - 80 + 'px' });
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fc .fc-popover {
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
```